# CKEDITOR - IE 11 crashes when adding a div containing a table inside an li tag

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ckeditor4.x

This seems to be related to one of the windows security updates after end of July. I have a page with ckeditor on it. We have some customized code to develop html using this ckeditor. When I try to add a div element containing a table inside an li tag, as soon as the element is added, IE 11 crashes with access violation exception in mshtml.dll. But the same div element when added outside of the list is fine. I am yet to zero in on the update that introduced this problem but was wondering if anyone has noticed a similar behavior lately.

Comment: If you can crash IE by fiddling with some html, you should probably report it to MS. that's not a good sign...

Comment: I just found that ie 11.0.29(kb3139929) update introduced this regression. Yes, I will report this to MS